# Liipimaginebundle - images in FOR loop

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

I've got a problem with showing thumbnails using Liipimaginebundle in TWIG template.

I'm rendering an index:

```
return $this->render('ad/index.html.twig', array(
        'ads' => $ads,
    ));
```

and in index.html.twig I'm using FOR loop to show thumbnails related to ads.

```
{% for ad in ads %}
   //with parameter - doesn't work
   {% set img = ad.mainPhoto %}   
   <img src="{{ img | imagine_filter('thumb') }}" />  

   //working fine
   <img src="{{ asset('/uploads/2.png') | imagine_filter('thumb') }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

mainPhoto stores a path to photo related to current ad - for example:

```
/uploads/2.png
```

While using an "img" parameter, I've got an exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "path" for route "liip_imagine_filter" must match ".+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").

What is the correct way to define the path in this case?

Comment: Can you show us the type and content of `ad.mainPhoto`?

Comment: @Veve ad.mainPhoto is a string with path e.g. /uploads/2.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing only the path as a string to the `imagine_filter`, add the `asset` and it should work:

```
{% for ad in ads %}
   {% set img = ad.mainPhoto|default %}
   {% if img <> "" %}
       <img src="{{ asset(img) | imagine_filter('thumb') }}" />  
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! It was my bad... Unfortunately I had one "ad" without "mainPhoto"... that was the reason of exception. BTW img | imagine_filter('thumb') works too :)

Comment: It works... until you have different asset environments. (Think CDN, server for static files, ...). I've added a verification for mainPhoto based on the first part of your comment.